# How to select data from last 30 days and include empty rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the last 1 month attendance from database (Table `a_days`, `HrEmployee` and `HrAttLogsFormatted`) when it is empty or not. When the data is empty I want to display "-" when there is display data from `LogsFormatted.DateIn`, and it can be in `WHERE BETWEEN` with `(Y-m-d)` date format. (Example from `2018-06-01` to `2018-06-10`)

**Query :**

```
SELECT
    Employee.Id as "EmployeeId",
    Employee.Name as "Name",
    TheDay.Days as "Date",
    LogsFormatted.DateIn as "DateIn",
    LogsFormatted.ScanIn as "ScanIn"
FROM
    HrEmployee as Employee
    LEFT JOIN HrEmployeeShift as EmployeeShift ON Employee.ShiftId = EmployeeShift.Id
    LEFT JOIN HrAttMachine as Machine ON Employee.MachineIP = Machine.IP
    LEFT JOIN HrAttLogsFormatted as LogsFormatted ON LogsFormatted.FingerId = Employee.Id
    LEFT JOIN a_days as TheDay ON TheDay.Days = DATE_FORMAT(LogsFormatted.DateIn, "%d")
WHERE Employee.ShiftId = EmployeeShift.Id
AND Employee.Id = '14522228'
ORDER BY Employee.Id, Employee.Name, TheDay.Days, LogsFormatted.DateIn ASC
```

**Result:**

```
FingerId    Name                Date   DateIn        ScanIn
14522228    Aldan Rizki Santosa 3      2018-07-06    06:45:54
14522228    Aldan Rizki Santosa 4      2018-07-09    06:38:12
14522228    Aldan Rizki Santosa 5      2018-07-10    06:48:35
```

**What I want:**

```
FingerId    Name                Date   DateIn        ScanIn
14522228    Aldan Rizki Santosa 1      -             -
14522228    Aldan Rizki Santosa 2      -             -
14522228    Aldan Rizki Santosa 3      2018-07-06    06:45:54
14522228    Aldan Rizki Santosa 4      2018-07-09    06:38:12
14522228    Aldan Rizki Santosa 5      2018-07-10    06:48:35
14522228    Aldan Rizki Santosa 6      -             -
.....
..... 
..... Until the date at the end of the month
```

Comment: Research on using a "calendar table."  You need to bring in the missing days somehow.

Comment: Take a look at joining a table containing all the days in your time range https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101157/how-to-display-all-the-dates-between-multiple-two-dates-in-a-table

Comment: @jspcal it's static date? what about date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the below query and check?

```
SELECT
     EmployeeDetail.EmployeeId
    ,EmployeeDetail.Name
    ,TheDay.rn AS Days
    ,EmployeeDetail.DateIn
    ,EmployeeDetail.ScanIn
FROM
    (SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, '2018-01-01', DATEADD(MONTH,1,'2018-01-01'))) 
     rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
     FROM sys.all_objects AS s1
     CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
     ORDER BY s1.[object_id]
    ) TheDay OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT 
     Employee.Id as EmployeeId,
    Employee.Name as Name,
    TheDay.rn as Date,
    LogsFormatted.DateIn as "DateIn",
    LogsFormatted.ScanIn as "ScanIn"
    FROM HrEmployee as Employee
    LEFT JOIN HrEmployeeShift as EmployeeShift ON Employee.ShiftId = EmployeeShift.Id
    LEFT JOIN HrAttMachine as Machine ON Employee.MachineIP = Machine.IP
    LEFT JOIN HrAttLogsFormatted as LogsFormatted ON LogsFormatted.FingerId = Employee.Id
    WHERE LogsFormatted.DateIn = TheDay.rn) AS EmployeeDetail
WHERE EmployeeDetail.EmployeeId = '14522228'
ORDER BY EmployeeDetail.Id, EmployeeDetail.Name, TheDay.Days, EmployeeDetail.DateIn ASC
```

Comment: i try the query and got error, **Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'**